# Basic Auth over HTTPS Java

Tags: java, https, basic-authentication

I have HTTPS page calls working fine and I have HTTP Basic Auth working fine what I can not do is get Basic Auth running on a HTTPS connection.

I attach a code example but it doesn't work. I keep getting a 403. I have checked the username and password and it has been successful when testing it with the [RESTClinet](http://restclient.net/) addon from Firefox.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
   private static void getAPITest() throws MalformedURLException, IOException 
{        
    try {


    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/home/USER/CERTS/myTrustStore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "PASSWORD");


     Authenticator myAuth = new Authenticator() 
        {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("USERNAME", "PASSWORD".toCharArray());
            }
        };

        Authenticator.setDefault(myAuth);


        String httpsURL = "https://someurlandapi.com";
        URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
        //con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authString);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");            

        InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
          System.out.println(inputLine);
        }

        ins.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it turns out don't have a space before the basic:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
```

and it needed:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5");
```

A quick note for anyone doing this if you are creating your own truststore you will need to add the sites/urls SSL certificate chain. In firefox you can click on the padlock > More information > security > view certificates.  From there you can highlight the certificate export with chain it then add it to your truststore with the keytool:

```
keytool -import -file websitecertificate.pem -alias websitecert -keystore myTrustStore
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think PasswordAuthentication is doing what you want.  But basic auth is really easy to handle yourself.  If you're in Java8 it is simply Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( ("USERNAME" + ":" + "PASSWORD").getBytes()).